# Issue with Android IAP, no OrderID in Purchase Object

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, google-play, subscription

Im testing Android In app purchase subscription with one of my accounts with TEST License access (I'm aware Test access won't support Subscriptions).
Noticed that there is no `orderId`in purchase response JSON but payment goes through(no charges though since there's a trail for 7 days on this subscription). response json looks like:

```
"packageName": "com.xxx.xxxx",
"productId": "yyyyyyyyyy_sdsda",
"purchaseTime": 1426055867418,
"purchaseState": 0,
"purchaseToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"autoRenewing": true
```

No 'ORDERID' is found. Tried switching to another Wallet account but no luck. Any clue??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've tried to reach Google support on this issue and it looks like they've added support for TEST access to subscriptions as well. i.e No order ID will be assigned for TEST accounts. Here's the response in their words:

> The team said that is working as expected as our payments system (Wallet) will not actually process anything so an order ID will never be assigned. I know it's not ideal for test purposes but that's currently how it works.

Posting it here hoping it would help others to understand these changes.