# Identify test GooglePlay purchases

Tags: xamarin, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

I have three different subscription purchases with different duration. I've configured test accounts and I can do test purchases. For those purchases Google doesn't charge me, but they look pretty much like real ones. When purchase is successfull, In-App Billing sends me some data about my purchase like `packageName`, `productId`, `orderId`, `purchaseToken` and so on.

In my handling code I need to know somehow if this purchase is real or not. In plain text: did I really earn money for it or was this purchase made by some test account and I earned for it nothing? I need this kind of info for purchases accounting.

So the question is: How do I distinguish between real and test subscription purchases in code?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm using Xamarin and C# for development.

Comment: I'm not sure I 'fully' understand your question, but on the physical device we used the fact the we are tagging the apk release version as an 'alpha' or 'beta' and thus those versions are only used by testers that have opted-in to the alpha/beta program (alpha=internal testers, beta = external testers for us at least), thus live apps = real $. Thus when we forward (from the phone) to our servers that a purchase was made, those records with this extra info and also save them with a `14-day` test flag as the order will be cancelled at that point.  lol, I'm close to want you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, kind of. But here are two questions: can I somehow make a real purchase on alpha/beta version? can I somehow make test purchase on production app version?

Comment: Ahh, got it now, and yes, random's answer is what was done on one project for 'real' users...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make real purchase on a alpha/ beta version if your account is not added to licensed accounts list in your Google Play developer account.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html):

> With alpha/beta test groups, real users (chosen by you) can install
>   your app from Google Play and test your in-app products. They can make
>   real purchases that result in actual charges to their accounts, using
>   any of their normal payment methods in Google Play to make purchases.
>   Note that if you include test license accounts in your alpha and beta
>   distribution groups, those users will only be able to make test
>   purchases.

**UPDATE**

To know which purchase is real and which is test one, check for orderId in response. No orderId will be assigned for test purchases.

[Issue with Android IAP, no OrderID in Purchase Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981224/issue-with-android-iap-no-orderid-in-purchase-object?lq=1)

Comment: Yes, exactly. So on alpha/beta versions it is possible to make both real and test purchases. And the same thing for production version. And my question is: how do I know which purchase is real and which is test one?

Comment: Damn, that easy? They should have written this with caps lock somewhere in documentation.. I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Test purchases doesn't have `orderId`. Thanks.

Comment: "To know which purchase is real and which is test one, check for orderId in response. No orderId will be assigned for test purchases." <== This is no longer true. Test orderId purchases now have the same orderId as regular purchases. (my team used the same method, and is looking for a different solution to that now)

Answer (score 3):

On the latest v3 Android Publisher API, you can obtain a SubscriptionPurchase object provided you have the Package name, SubscriptionId and the Token.
The SubscriptionPurchase object contains an optional (null-able) integer field named **purchaseType**. According to Google, when it is set and the value is 0, this is a Test subscription. I can confirm this works and matches the data I am getting back.
Here is the quote from Google's documentation:

```
    //     The type of purchase of the subscription. This field is only set if this purchase
    //     was not made using the standard in-app billing flow. Possible values are: 0.
    //     Test (i.e. purchased from a license testing account) 1. Promo (i.e. purchased
    //     using a promo code)
```